# GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in OpenGL ES/WebGL?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, texture-mapping

I have an application in mind that would greatly benefit from the use of [array textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture). However, I have not been able to determine whether array textures are available in the current WebGL specification and/or in OpenGL ES 2.0, on which WebGL is based.

Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the answer is pretty old now, and the page keeps getting high rank in search engines, better says here that array textures are now avaliable with the `webgl2` context (OpenGL ES 3.0).

You might want to check browser compatibility https://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl2

Comment: Thanks, I'm switching the accepted answer to reflect the changing times ;)

Answer (score 7):

[EDIT 7 years later]: Since I answered this the specification has changed, and now allows for GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY.

Comment: @ArneBergeneFossaa can you reference the spec that leads you to this conclusion?